# Check and edit Process Logical count + Fail proof

Tags: c#

I have created this code but trying to add some more function to it

```
public static int HowManyCores()
{
   int CoresNumber = Environment.ProcessorCount;
    try
    {
        return CoresNumber;
    }
    catch
    {
        return CoresNumber = 2;
    }
}
```

I want the function to return "2" if it failed for any reason. Also I would like to return CoresNumber -1 (So if it finds 4 it returns 3) also another case: if CoresNumer less than 2 (Including) return 2.

Comment: a return statement of a calculated variable will never fail, there's no reason to wrap it with a try. If you want to use a try/catch, wrap something that can throw an exception

Comment: @Vadim there is no chance in some PC that this function will not be able to return a logical process number? This is good :)

Comment: @PeakDermutag, I only said that once you have the int, returning it will not fail. Setting it might.

Comment: @Vadim ah so I set the try catch all wrong :) so I will set it on the `Environment.ProcessorCount` thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove try catch and use

```
return CoresNumber > 2 ? CoresNumber - 1 : 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

As Vadim stated, it will not throw an exception. So you could try:

```
public static int GetCoreCount()
{
    int cores = Environment.ProcessorCount;

    if (cores <= 2) { return 2; }
    else { return cores - 1; }
}
```

Comment: does it work on windows xp? [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.processorcount.aspx)I don't see it on the link Platforms: so try catch can be useful for setting the value if the OS is not supported? I tested your code it works on windows 8 can we add some catch for it if the function doesn't work? I will want to have some value or my program will fail...

Answer (score 0):

i can give you this code:

```
public static int HowManyCores()
{
    int CoresNumber = -1;
    try
    {
        CoresNumber = Environment.ProcessorCount;
        if (CoresNumber <= 2) { CoresNumber = 2; }
    }
    catch
    {
        // Log maybe
    }

    return CoresNumber;
}
```

though you can read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.processorcount.aspx) that it shouldn't throw any exceptions

Comment: does it work on windows xp? I don't see it on the link Platforms: so try catch can be useful for setting the value if the OS is not supported?

Comment: @PeakDermutag a quick search on top of what i read on MSDN shows that it will always return a value, and not a single exception i found out about...